# how to attach ajax to the follow/unfollow links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, page-refresh

I got the following code in my tag.html.erb:

The link for unfollow:

```html
<a style="margin-top:-8px;" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you'd like to unfollow this topic?" rel="tooltip" title="<%= t('tag.show.unfollow') %>" class="pull-right" href="/unsubscribe/tag/<%= tag.name %>" data-remote="true" onclick="window.location.reload(true);"><i style="color:#ccc;" class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

The link for follow:

```html
<a style="width: 100px;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm index-follow-buttons follow-btn-remote" href="/subscribe/tag/<%= tag.name %>" data-remote="true"><%= t('tag.index.follow') %></a>
```

At present after clicking on the following links, the page needs to be refreshed to see the changes. Is there a way so that just on clicking on these links the page automatically gets refreshed or any other solution? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: You want to toggle the two links without refresh the page, right?

Comment: @sam, yes, I have tried `onclick="window.location.reload(true);"` , but it didn't work.

Comment: OK, got it. You set `data-remote="true"`, so it's AJAX. in your action, you can handle the request by adding `format.js` respond, then add some javascript to replace your link.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the controller action with the redirect_back method. The redirect_back method redirects the browser to the page that issued the request.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Place at the end of your controller's action that is handling each request:

```rb
def controller_action

  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end
```

If the request is missing this header, the fallback_location will be used. You can set the fallback location to whatever route you would like, including the route that renders tag.html.erb

Comment: Can you provide an example solution or otherwise your answer might better be added as a comment.

Comment: I just provided an example solution. I hope that was adequate.